# Google tags, Code apears in my site

Tags: google-tag-manager

I put google tags on my website and when I open the page it shows the code, how to solve it?

```
<head><script>
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');
</script>
```

**and**

```
  <body>
    <noscript>
        <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
    </noscript>
    </body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you have a custom HTML tag with a Facebook tag and forgot to wrap this in `<script></script>` tags (also your example code is missing the script tags around the GTM script. Also don't be confused by the fact that the word "tag" has three different meanings in this sentence).

Add script HTML tags (`<script></script>` ) to you FB tag and publish, then the problem should be solved.

Comment: I edit this question, please take a look, i still have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not your "Google Tags", it's a custom tag you've used (facebook as i look in your code) You must have forgot   around a custom tag. Dig in your tag section of GTM.